# Create class instance with string input (python)

Tags: python, string, input, instantiation

I want to create class instances and name them with user input strings. Something like this, that actually works. Any ideas?

```
class Account:
     balance=0

input("What's your name?") = Account()
```

If the user were to type Scott, I would like to be able to call attributes using Scott.balance etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off storing them in a dictionary.  Creating variables in the global / local space with user input is a recipe for trouble.

```
accounts = {}
account[x] = Account()
```

Comment: So this would create an instance in an array, which is nice. But How would I incorporate a user's name to name the array, which would allow me to call it's properties with the syntax i.e. Jack.balance?

Comment: `account[name].balance += 100`

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in `raw_input` to have user input as argument of your 'constructor'

```
class Account:
     def __init__(self, name=0, money=0):
         self.name = name
         self.money = money

input = raw_input("What's your name? -->")
account = Account(input,10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your class an `__init__` method:

```
class Account:
     def __init__(self, x=1, y=2):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
```

And just initialize it:

```
def createAccount(x):
    return Account(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can input string from outside the class by just passing it in to init as normal using two ways : input() or raw_input().

```
class Account:
     def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance
     def output_all(self):
        print( '{}'.format(self.balance))

MyAccount = Account(input('Type your account : '))

Account.output_all(MyAccount)
```

Comment: It will be great if you will explain your approach with the added code.

Comment: We can input string from outside the class by just passing it in to init as normal using two ways : input() or raw_input().      

I hope that i well explained !

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the input to a list, then create an instance of the class by referencing the list element:

```
class Account:
     balance=0

account_names = []

account_names.append(input("What's your name?"))

account_names[0] = Account()
```

To change/access class attribute, reference the list element:

```
>>> account_names[0].balance += 100
>>> account_names[0].balance
100
```