# Instance of a Class Using a Variable Python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to initialize a class within a function that has the name of the soon to be created object passed into the function like so....

```
def createPlayer(name):
    name = Player(name1,0)
```

Where the name variable in `createPlayer(name)` is the name of the initialized class as seen in `name = Player(name1,0)`

Currently python does not recognize that the "name" variable being passed into the function is the same as the one creating the instance of the class `Player()`

Is this possible?

I would like to not have to use a dispatcher as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2136854).

*This is my first post to stackoverflow I don't know all the syntax standards of the community so any pointers would be appreciated.*

Comment: Is this something you have done in other languages and are wondering if you can do it in python?  How would you use such a class in the rest of your program?  It is not clear the usefulness of this.  Could you explain further?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to accomplish, but perhaps read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html before clarifying your question.

Comment: The closest I can imagine to what you are trying to do here is you should create a dictionary of all your generated classes and use the name as the key to access the class objects.

Comment: I am trying to have user input create a new instance of the class named after the name the user inputs, this is most likely not the optimal way to accomplish such task but I was curious if python could do it.

Comment: my objective is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098845/create-class-instance-with-string-input-python